# Unable to retrieve auth properties from firebase cloud function

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have written a callable cloud function which requires user auth details, documentation says it is automatically sent to cloud functions but i am unable to access it.

[image]

```
export const createProfile = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const driver = neo4j.v1.driver("uri", neo4j.v1.auth.basic("usr", "pwd")
    )
    const session = driver.session()

    session.writeTransaction(wrte=>
      wrte.run('CREATE (a:Person) SET a.name ={displayName}, a.emailAddress={emailAddress}, a.uniqueID ={uniqueID}  RETURN a', 
      {displayName: 'Vinay', uniqueID: context.auth.uid, emailAddress: context.auth.token.email })
      )
}
```

Comment: Are those values actually undefined when you call your cloud function? That message in your IDE is just a warning, it doesn't mean that they'll actually _be_ undefined at runtime, just that they can be and if they are it'll throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `auth` property on `context` is defined in TypeScript as possibly undefined.  Note the question mark in the property definition.  Auth is defined like this because there might not be a user signed into the app at the time the callable is invoked, and this is how the SDK is signaling to you about this case.

This means you should be checking for undefined before using is properties, since that would crash during runtime.

```
if (context.auth) {
    // now it's safe to use context.auth.id,
    // since TypeScript is sure that context.auth can't be undefined.
}
```